# Mod_Rewrite index.php?page=users&id=1 to /users/4

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i'm looking for a technique to rewrite the `index.php?page=users&id=1` to `/users/1/`. I found some snippets for my .htaccess but nothing worked for me. I also reading rewrite doc

I've got `$_GET['page']` in my root index.php so my url is `index.php?page=users` and inside my `users.php` i've got `$_GET['id']` so my url is `index.php?page=users&id=1`

How do I get with rewrite `/users/4/`

Tried rule is:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/([0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2
```

Comment: You want to change the links to `/users/#` then do a rewrite rule. Please add what you've tried so we can advise how to change it.

Comment: i've tried this one `RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2`, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696718/htaccess-rewrite-book-phpid-1234-to-book-1234) one

Comment: Do you know what that says? `([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)` <> `/users/4/` Good place to test regexs https://regex101.com/

Comment: regex said there must be a backslash between `([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)` so this is what it looks now `RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)\/([0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2` but it still won't work. if i type `/users/1` i've got a blank page

Comment: Now im trying [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26295608/12004521) one and it won't work too

Comment: `[0-9]+` matches multiple digits from 0 through 9, and you have put that in the place where your URL actually contains `users`, so of course this doesn’t match.

Comment: Ok, someone deleted his comments. My actual .htaccess is following ``RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /driver

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/(\d+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [QSA,L]`` and i want ``index.php?page=users&id=1`` to ``/users/1`` and ``index.php?page=home`` to ``/home``